# DevExpress XtraReport - Round Down

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

Can you tell me how to do rounding like in crystal report? eg: round([field],-2)

How to do Round like the example above. Like we did on Crystal Report. I want to do rounding down on DevExpress XtraReport.

If it value eg. 2514942 I want output: 2514900

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

you can use CalculatedField for such functionality

1. add calc field on the same level as your "[field]"
2. assign to the calc field the expression like "Round([field] / 100, 2) * 100" to reset last two numbers
3. bind your control to newly created calc field

also here [tutorial for the calc fields](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4801)